# AWS API GW root proxy resource and route proxy resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

We have an AWS Rest API GW that has a single proxy resource at root connected to a lambda function:

```
/
 /{proxy+} -> Lambda 1
```

We are wanting to start splitting this up into multiple lambdas, and have deployed the API like:

```
/
  /service1
    /{proxy+} -> Lambda 2
  /{proxy+} -> Lambda 1
```

The problem is, if we just make a request like `GET /service1`, the request is handled by `Lambda 1` instead of `Lambda 2`.

Now that I have this problem, it makes total that it would work this way, but I am wondering if there is a way to get the desired behavior of this request being handled by `Lambda 2`